# Application Installation Failed with message Invalid File

Tags: android, android-studio

My friend is developing an app, and he gave me his project on a USB drive. My problem is that when I try to run it on my Mac, it gives me this error:

> #### Application Installation Failed
>
> Installation failed with message Invalid File: [...].apk.
>   It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing.

[image: this is my error, I need to change the directory]

How or where to change the settings or the direction in Android Studio?

Comment: I think it's just a simple keystore conflict issues, may solved by copying your debug keystore from original computer to your Mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same problem , just choose clean project then rebuild project from build menu , it's solved my problem